# Implementing long-polling database calls in a signalR hub

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I have a hub that takes a request from the client like this:

```
 [HubName("Check")]
    public class Check : Hub
    {
        private long _sessionId;
        private string _sortType;
        private int _tableCount;
        private Timer _timer;

        public void Car(long sessionId, string sortType, int tableCount)
        {
            _sessionId = sessionId;
            _sortType = sortType;
            _tableCount = tableCount;
            StartCarTimer();
        }

        public void StartCarTimer()
        {
            _timer = new Timer(3000);
            _timer.Elapsed += CarTimerElapsed;
            _timer.Start();
        }

        void CarTimerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {  
            int countCars = CountCars();

            if (countCarPrices > _tableCount)
            {
                _tableCount = countCarPrices;
                Clients.All.car(GetCarTable());
            }   
        }


        private int GetCars()
        {
            CarPrices carPrices = new CarPriceRepository().FindCarPricesById(_sessionId);
            return carPrices;
        }
    }
```

I simplified it a little bit but basically I'm polling the database every 3 seconds to check for changes, which really feels like horrible design. I've been looking everywhere on how to solve this without any result.

One method suggested by a friend is to notify the signalR hub on the server side from the service that updates the database, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Can somebody please point me in the right direction?

Comment: You could write a new web service to communicate between the 2 apps when there has been an update

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to do and what problem do you have?

Comment: It's pretty clear in the question what I am trying to do and what problem I have. lol...

Answer (score -1):

signalr works between at least 2 clients
client A,connection and wait a message,
client B,do something(begin a request to server),server notice client A revice a message

```
GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<T>().Clients
```

you can use this to get all clients anywhere
clients same as Clients property in hub
and

```
Clients.Group("groupName").method(param)
```

some code like this ,can notice the clients who you want to notice,method is a js method in,it auto generat by signalr the name same as you hub method(first letter lowercase)